# Using factory pattern for various components/modules

Tags: oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern, solid-principles

Let's say we have a system that builds articles. The article has some components validator, cleaner, storage.... In the client to build an article I have to instantiate each component:

```
    $title = 'title';
    $description = 'Description in html';

    //Cleaner just clean some things from each field.
    $cleaner = new Cleaner();

    //Validator throw exception if something is not correct
    $validator = new Validator();

    // Storage save files and article itself
    $storage = new Storage();

    //Dom Class get some files from description field
    $dom = new Dom();
    $files = $dom->getFiles($description);

    $storage->files($files);

    $article = new ArticleBuilder();
    $article->addTitle($validator->title($cleaner->title($title)));
    $article->addDescription($validator->description($cleaner->description($description)));
    $article->add....
```

Without these it's impossible to build an article.

**My question is:**
Can I use the factory pattern to create all of these like this:

```
          class ArticleFactory
        {
            private $article;

            public function __construct()
            {
                $this->article = new ArticleBuilder();
            }

            public function setTitle(string $title)
            {
                $title = ($this->validator())->title($title);
                $title = ($this->cleaner())->title($title);
                $this->article->addTitle($title);
            }

            public function setDescription(string $des)
            {
                $des = ($this->validator())->title($des);
                $des = ($this->cleaner())->title($des);
                $this->article->addDescription($des);
            }

            public function getArticle(): ArticleBuilder
            {
                return $this->article;
            }

            public function getFiles($description)
            {
               return ($this->dom())->getFiles($description);
            }

            public function storeFile($files)
            {
                ($this->storage())->files($files);
            }

            public function validator(): ValidatorInterface
            {
                return new Validator();
            }

            public function cleaner(): CleanerInterface
            {
                return new Cleaner();
            }

            public function storage(): StorageInterface
            {
                return new Storage();
            }

            public function dom(): DomInterface
            {
                return new Dom();
            }
        }
```

In the client is more convenient to create an article with the above factory:

```
        $myTitle = 'my title';
        $myDes = 'mty description';
        $article = new ArticleFactory();
        $article->setTitle($myTitle);
        $article->setDescription($myDes);
        $files = $article->getFiles($description);
        $article->storeFile($files);
```

Is this violates any of the SOLID principles?

Is there any better approach about this?

Comment: **Can I use the factory pattern to create all of these** Of course you can. The question is how useful is it going to be. And for that we would need to ask our crystal ball, because you provided zero context.

Comment: I don't understand this too well. You have an `ArticleFactory` but you're returning `Validator`, `Cleaner` and `Storage` types. Are these derivatives or dependencies of `Article`?

Comment: I've updated my answered. Let me know if you want something more. Thank you

Comment: Your design is definitely odd, but you would have to explain the entire problem domain so that we can offer a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

The class `ArticleFactory` seems to be violating `SRP` because `ArticleFactory` is concerned with more than one thing (building, storing, validating and cleaning articles).

There also seems to be a confusion here between the `Factory` pattern and the `Builder` pattern. If the class `ArticleFactory` also builds articles then it would be cleaner if it had (composition) a builder and delegated the building process to it. Do you really need a builder? Is the process of creating new articles so complicated/expensive that the builder pattern will add value?

The usage of nouns in the names of functions (`function Validator`, `Cleaner`, `Storage`) makes the code difficult to understand. What was your intention there?

Use verbs for functions and nouns for classes.